# Nuxt2 Router.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, router

I have a stupid simple question that I basically failed to find a good answer for.
I have a nuxt2 project that has a @nuxtjs/router module on it. I have added the module on the buildModules on nuxt.config.js and created router.js on the src folder.

this is my nuxt.config.js file :

```
    ssr: true,     // tauri 
 target: 'static', // tauri     
  server : {
    host:"127.0.0.1",
    port: 8001
  },

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    ...
  },
  env:{
    MEDIA_API:process.env.VUE_APP_MEDIA_API,
    API_URL: process.env.API_URL

  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    ...
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
  '@nuxtjs/router'
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    ...
    '@nuxtjs/router',
    ...
  ],

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    plugins: [ // to import jQuery :" 
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        'window.$': 'jquery',
      }),
    ],
    standalone: true
  },

  router: {
    middleware: ['auth']
  },

  auth: {
    ...
  }
```

and here is my router.js file :

```
import { parseHTML } from 'jquery';
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(Router)

// this is just a function to help me not writing the full path of each page
const page = (path) => () => import(`~/pages/${path}`).then(m => m.default || m)

const routes = [
  {path: '/', name: 'home', component: page('index.vue')},
  {path: '/login', name: 'login', component: page('login.vue')},
  {path: '/players', name: 'allPlayers', component: page('players/index.vue')},
  {path: '/players/:id', name: 'singlePlayer', component: page('players/view.vue')},
  {path: '/plans', name: 'allPlans', component: page('plans/index.vue')},
  {path: '/plans/new', name: 'newPlan', component: page('plans/new.vue')},
  {path: '/activities', name : 'allActs', component: page ('activities/index.vue')},
  {path: '/activities/new', name: 'newAct', component: page('activities/new.vue')},
  {path: '/activityPlayer/:id', name: 'viewActivityPlayer', component: page('activities/viewActivityPlayer')},
  {path: '/auth/login', name: 'auth.login', component: page('auth/login')},
  {path: '/superAdmin/', name: 'superAdmin', component: page('superAdmin/index.vue')},
  {path: '/superAdmin/viewAll', name: 'viewAdmins', component: page('superAdmin/viewAdmins.vue')},


];


export function createRouter() {
  return new Router({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
  })
}
```

I want to generate full static build to deploy my nuxt app on a tauri build. I was able to successfully deploy a nuxt app that does NOT has that router.js file. The build `generate` just generate all routes by default in the dist folder.

How can I generate the routes ?

Comment: You have it in `buildModules` and `modules`, keep it only for `buildModules`. Also, do you have any kind of error or alike? What do you have in `dist` directory VS a classic router generated by Nuxt?

Comment: I have only the 200.html page in my build vs the calsic being index.html + 200.html + some other stuff

Comment: and nope. No build errors.

Comment: Btw, why do you want that module? Isn't [extras](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module) enough configuration-wise?

Comment: I have tried to remove it from modules and keep it on buildModules only and it did NOT work :"" @kissu

Comment: I feel like router.js makes it more organized for me. I really dont like the one-file thing in nuxt..

Comment: Where is your router file located?

Comment: in the same folder with nuxt.config.js. Both of them located in the source folder which is the project folder that contain all other folders like node_modules, .nuxt and dist.

Comment: Your router configuration is correct and perfectly working on my side. Could you try commenting out `middleware: ['auth']`, I'm pretty sure the issue is coming from here. Explanation being that you have a global auth middleware protecting all of your routes, hence they cannot be generated ahead of time because they would not be protected anymore. Hence why you don't have any routes generated.

Comment: Sadly that did not work either. D:

Comment: Is your project public?

Comment: yub yub 

here it is : 
https://github.com/GemyPs/ForsanGYM

Comment: Also I have noticed when I remove middleware: ['auth'] the app stops at the loading screen

Comment: Yeah, probably of all the other places that depend on it. Quick debug trick, doesn't grant stability to the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried with the `/login` path and it's working great as shown in [this commit](https://github.com/kissu/ForsanGYM/commit/134850ea31333976d43c9386b35c82de6cc42cba), there was [a typo](https://github.com/kissu/ForsanGYM/commit/134850ea31333976d43c9386b35c82de6cc42cba#diff-a73fe0e0bce14920155c1577b261b025ced6d28bf11c113f8b86cb5f429ee471R11) in the path tho (I did tried only for that one since it was an obvious one for me).

I also removed the useless `package-lock.json` since you use yarn in your project (could be vice-versa of course) and since you should not use both at the same time. Added a few explicit keys in the `nuxt.config.js` file too.

Commented `@nuxtjs/auth-next`, ran `yarn generate && yarn start` and I have successfully access to the given path.

The generated route files are maybe not that friendly (because of their hash) but they are still available in the `dist` directory. There is a way to make them prettier, you could search for that on Stackoverflow/Google.

---

Update: it works with the auth middleware [too actually](https://github.com/kissu/ForsanGYM/commit/179857b2e178e1e84589f21061576e99399a684e).

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm.. Okay that is working but the problem remains. I still can not produce a fully static version in the dist folder :'

Comment: In the normal nuxt app >> an index.html and all other pages will be produced in that folder..

Comment: What I meant is the app has no entry point to it's login page. Even if that entry point is defined in the router file.

Comment: and by the way. Thanks a lot man <33

Comment: Then, I guess that this one is missing: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#function-with-a-callback The crawler is probably not doing it's job if you handle the router manually. @abdullah35

Comment: HUH. I didnt quite get it. what crawler? The link you sent me is just a callback function

Comment: @abdullah35 à crawler is getting all the routes by default (when using the file system routing). https://nuxtjs.org/announcements/going-full-static/#crawler-integrated If you want to set it manually yourself, use the callback function.